# Returning a substring from the value field of an xml doc using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

The XML field is as such :

```
<Element> 0 (0)</Element>
```

As far as I know this should do what I wish, you can ignore the irrelevant part (e.Descendants) as this is correct (and I have verified this) in the greater scheme of my query. :

```
Regex regularExpression = new Regex(@"(\d+) \((\d+)\)", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

And the Linq to XML in question :

```
variableName =  e.Descendants().Where(i => regularExpression.IsMatch(i.Value.ToString())).Select(j => regularExpression.Match(j.Value.ToString()).Groups[1].Value.ToString()).ToList()
```

However when I attempt to print this value, it is not printing anything.

What have I done incorrectly here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should use `'\s'` instead of `' '`:

```
Regex regEx2 = new Regex(@"(\d+)\s\((\d+)\)", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```